# How to show the lookup data by its name in list view of Child object

Tags: visualforce, salesforce-id

I have two custom object Labs and Company Company has lookup relation in lab. Company has thre fields Name as CompnayId whic auto-generated, CompanyName_*c and CompanyDescription*_c, when I click on Tab of lab I am able to see the Companyid onlt in the lsitview, how I can be able to see the Company by CompanyName__c field. thanks in advance

Regards
Raman

Answer (score 1):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp4N

Unfortunately this is under  idea .You cannot cross reference parent fields .You can vote for idea above .You can build visualforce if you need this functionality badly with spending some  effort.

Comment: Thanks Mohith but I got the solution for this thanks

Comment: @Raman If you have some alternative solution its better to post it here as this will help others searching for solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the custom field of one  object on Second object, I would suggest to create a Formula field on Second object that takes the value from  custom Field of one object.

Once this field is there, you can then create a custom list view and display the Custom Field on the list view.